SQL get one result of counted column
I have a problem in DB2 getting exactly one (random) result from a column, that is actually counted.
table:
name, objA, objS, category, status, all varchar
I count all "name" where objA and objS are similar like this:
SELECT
objA,
objS,
COUNT (name) AS COUNT_NAME
FROM myTable
WHERE
category = 'testuser'
AND status NOT IN ('removed', 'invalid', 'suspended') 
GROUP BY
objA,
objB

This works.
Now I want to add a column to the result, which has exactly one value of the "name" in it and I do not care, which one. I was going for the first.
Unfortunately, the
FIRST_VALUE (name) OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name ) testValue
Requires an additional GROUP BY for "name" which completely destroys the purpose of the query.
I was trying the dumb approach to just collect all names with LISTAGG and then get one of these. This would have worked but I get 4000+ results at one time so the DB2 just cancels the request (I see the point).
Approach via subquery on top level got me only to get the first of all names, not the counted ones.
How can I get ONE result of the counted names without breaking the query?
Thanks in advance

How about MIN(name)?

Aggregating (min, max) should help you get one name value.
For example of table orders as shown below:

You can make use of the following queries:

Which will give you resultset as follows:


This helped a lot, thanks
Adding MIN(name) as example below the count.
